# How to stop the sound in pgzrun (Pygame Zero) when my game ends?

Tags: python, pgzero

the sound plays right now for eternity and I only want it to play once when the game ends. I've looked it up everywhere but I really cannot find any good and helpful solution to this problem.

I use pygame zero.
Here is my code for my game:

```
import pgzrun
from random import randint

'''
music
music = pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
'''

#mixer
music.play("music")
music.set_volume(0.3)
sounds.effect1.set_volume(0.2)
sounds.effect2.set_volume(0.3)

BREDD = 400
HOJD = 400
summa = 0
spelet_slut = False

rav = Actor("fox")
rav.pos = 100,100

mynt = Actor("coin")
mynt.pos = 200,200

apple = Actor("apple")
apple.pos = 300,300

def draw():
    screen.fill("blue")
    rav.draw()
    mynt.draw()
    apple.draw()
    screen.draw.text("Summa: " + str(summa), color="black", topleft=(10,10))
        
    if spelet_slut:
        music.stop()
        screen.fill("red")
        screen.draw.text("Slutsumma: " + str(summa), topleft=(10,10), fontsize=60)
        sounds.lose.play()
        
        
def placera_mynt():
    mynt.x = randint(20, (BREDD - 20))
    mynt.y = randint(20, (HOJD - 20))

def placera_apple():
    apple.x = randint(20, (BREDD - 20))
    apple.y = randint(20, (HOJD - 20))

def tiden_slut():
    global spelet_slut
    spelet_slut = True

def update():
    global summa
    
    if keyboard.left:
        rav.x = rav.x - 4
    elif keyboard.right:
        rav.x = rav.x + 4
    elif keyboard.up:
        rav.y = rav.y - 4
    elif keyboard.down:
        rav.y = rav.y + 4

    insamlade_mynt = rav.colliderect(mynt)
    insamlade_apple = rav.colliderect(apple)

    if insamlade_mynt:
        summa = summa + 10
        sounds.effect1.play()
        
        placera_mynt()
    elif insamlade_apple:
        summa = summa + 10
        sounds.effect2.play()
        placera_apple()

clock.schedule(tiden_slut, 5)
placera_mynt()
placera_apple()
pgzrun.go()
```

Comment: does play_once() work?

Answer (score 0):

instead of `music.play("music")` use `music.play_once("music")`

`music.play()`: Play a music track from the given file. The track will loop indefinitely.

`music.play_once`: Similar to play(), but the music will stop after playing through once.

try: music.stop() to stop the music

you can read more about there here:
https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/builtins.html#music

Comment: I've tried with that but it doesn't work is there another way?

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: look at your question first "How to stop the sound when the game ends"?

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>

You must read author's [GitHub](https://github.com/lordmauve/pgzero/issues/51) for details.